# What is this pale blue dot in a daytime photo of a Sun halo?

Tags: the-sun, photography, identify-this-object

This photo of the sun behind a cloud was taken on the south coast of England in early May 2021 using an iPhone 11. A halo is visible which I think is the 22-degree halo. However, the photo also shows a small, pale blue dot near the middle of the photo, within the photo, left and above the Sun. Please could somebody suggest what the blue dot is?
[image: Sun halo]

Comment: It could be a lens flare or some bad pixels in the photo.

Comment: Related: [Apparently two objects in Solar Eclipse image](/q/36626)

Comment: It's on the opposite side of the image center from the Sun, so does this answer your question? [Apparently two objects in Solar Eclipse image](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/36626/apparently-two-objects-in-solar-eclipse-image)

Comment: It should be the image of the bright source, Sun in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe this is the internal lens reflection. Lens reflections have hexagonal shape, and if you look closely, it somewhat resembles this shape. Also, see other answers in the comments.

Internal lens reflection happens because the lenses don't have 100% transmission. This often happens when taking bright objects, like Sun in your example.