# What is this planet or satellite in this picture?

Tags: star, planet, identify-this-object

[image: first image]

I took this photo in Shijiazhuang, Hebei Province, China, 38°13'N 115°18'E
(+38.23, +115.31) on the night of February 8, 2020. Here you can see a round object above the moon, and it was moving fast,the first photo was shot on 19:32:24, and the second was shot on 19:31:46. Can you please tell me what it was? Now that I have checked on SkyView Free, it seemed to be in the location of Pollux, but I don't think it was because it was big and it seemed like a planet which did not glow.

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to add the longitude/latitude of the image or the name of the city/town it was taken from?  "Northern China" is a pretty large region, and visibility times of individual satellites is heavily dependent on location.

Comment: [Heavens-Above](https://www.heavens-above.com/) is good for this sort of thing but not more than 3 months in the past.

Comment: @notovny ,thanks for your message, I have added the longitude/latitude info.

Comment: @mike-g, Thanks for your info, I'll check that out.

Comment: Not Pollux, but position of v Cnc (on the first picture).

Comment: Given the size of it, it was more likely a balloon than a satellite. By the way, while looking at the first photo in an image editor, trying to adjust the levels to see if any stars were visible (they weren't), I noticed an interesting-looking artefact at coordinates 1168, 392 - 1183, 399. It doesn't look like a usual JPEG artefact, rather some type of QR code. What is it?

Comment: @AaronF  I found your "QR" code.  It looks exactly like a jpeg artifact around a weak point source of light '

Comment: @JamesK aha, thank you! Then that's probably Procyon, I suppose

Comment: @frankchang1990 -  Could you see the object from your naked eyes? If so, this completely rules out MikeG's suggestion below. He says that it could be a reflection from the camera lens, but if you could see it through your naked eyes, then the camera won't affect it at all.

Comment: I don't remember that I can see it from my naked eyes, cause it was full moon, it was so bright. It make sense to suppose it was the reflection of the moon. Thank you all. I thought I discovered something :-)

Comment: @frankchang1990 welcome to Astronomy SE! Thanks for the edits (I trimmed the digits) See also [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/32951/7982) for a DYI test. If it works on your image, let us know! It's always okay to write an answer to your own question as long as it addresses the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in [this question](/q/36626) about an image of a partial solar eclipse, the object in question is:

- round and about half the apparent size of the Moon
- fainter and slightly bluish
- directly opposite the Moon relative to the center of the image

I believe it is a reflection of the Moon from coated surfaces in the camera lens.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ;-)