# Is this object Mars?

Tags: identify-this-object

[image: photo]

I decided to try the Astrophotography mode on my phone. Looking at the image I saw an object I didn't notice at the time.

What is the blue circle right of the Moon and just on the top right of the hole between the clouds?

---

I tried to look at [a planetarium](https://in-the-sky.org///skymap.php?no_cookie=1&latitude=43.22&longitude=27.92&timezone=3.00&year=2021&month=5&day=25&hour=21&min=37&PLlimitmag=2&zoom=109&ra=15.10718&dec=-26.27860&skin=0) (time and location included, no idea about the azimuth). I couldn't find a planet looking at this direction.

According to [this](https://in-the-sky.org/data/planets.php) (if I understand it correctly) the only planet visible at that time and location should have been Mars.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Help identify a bright and round object photographed through a telescope](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/34900/help-identify-a-bright-and-round-object-photographed-through-a-telescope)

Comment: @B--rian, according to https://in-the-sky.org/data/planets.php "Venus recently passed behind the Sun at superior solar conjunction. From Varna, it is not observable – it will reach its highest point in the sky during daytime and is no higher than 7° above the horizon at dusk.". Is the site just wrong or am I misinterpreting stuff?

Comment: @B--rian or if you're suggesting it's just a spec of dust on the lens - maybe it's possible. But I also took a couple of photos before and after that and they don't have the same "spot".

Comment: Welcome to astronomy SE! I am rather certain that is an effect of the lens - in any case a zoom-in of your object would be helpful, see also https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/43684/what-is-that-donut-shaped-object-i-see-in-my-telescope

Comment: @B--rian, thanks! If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: The official way for a question like this is close-as-duplicate your question rather than answering it - please do not feel dishearted by that.

Comment: Thanks for re-opening your question!

Comment: It's a an artifact produced in the optical system of the camera.  It might well be a reflected image of the moon.  What it isn't is a planet, which is not going to be imaged as a disc that large by a phone camera.

Comment: @tfb Unless if it was a rogue planet coming from interstellar space. That's what made this question so intriguing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this object Mars?

I'm pretty sure this is simple [lens flare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_flare).

While lens surfaces in cameras have antireflection coatings that strongly reduce reflections, they are not perfect. A very bright small spot like the Sun or Moon or a bright streetlight will result in near-mirror images opposite the center of the image.

Analysis from [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/32951/7982):

[image: lens flare exactly opposite the center of the image]

Here I used this effect *on purpose* to reduce the brightness of the partially eclipsed Sun before it became annular. [Solar eclipse of December 14, 2020](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_eclipse_of_December_14,_2020)):

[image: Partially eclipsed Sun December 14, 2020]

complete image:

[image: Partially eclipsed Sun December 14, 2020] click for larger